# Why does this code not work with Tron address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= _balances[msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    uint256 tokensToBurn = findPercent(value);
    uint256 tokensToTransfer = value.sub(tokensToBurn);

    _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(tokensToTransfer);
    balances[TX1Ce42x82qvQW7biLjuae2yGfkAWkP6kD] = 
    _balances[TX1Ce42x82qvQW7biLjuae2yGfkAWkP6kD].add(tokensToBurn);

   // _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokensToBurn);

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokensToTransfer);
    // burns to this address, this address will be the reward address
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, TX1Ce42x82qvQW7biLjuae2yGfkAWkP6kD, tokensToBurn);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Tron addresses directly on Ethereum (or in Solidity, as you have shown).